# Pandas 'Int64' type is converted to an 'object' type after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I noticed the following behaviour when working with [Int64](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html). Is there a way to avoid the type conversion and preserve the `Int64` type post merge?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [10, 11, 12]}, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
df = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', indicator=True, suffixes=('_x', ''))

df1.dtypes
Out[8]: 
col1    Int64
col2    Int64
dtype: object

df2.dtypes
Out[9]: 
col1    Int64
col2    Int64
dtype: object

df.dtypes
Out[10]: 
col1        object
col2        object
_merge    category
dtype: object
```

I should clarify that I am looking for an answer that doesn't involve explicitly doing something like:

```
for k, v in df1.dtypes.to_dict().items():
    df[k] = df[k].astype(v)
```

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8596, I think the problem is when do do outer , pandas is per-setting the column type to object for future `np.nan`

Comment: Upgrade pandas. I tried your code on version `0.24.2` and it preserves the `dtypes`

Comment: @Mstaino I'm on 0.25.1. You're not using 'Int64' - you must be using 'int64'.

Comment: No, I copied your first two lines of code as is. Now that I'm checking what I did was use `df1.merge` instead of `df2.merge`. Strange

Comment: @Mstaino This is to do with the fact that df1 contains all of df2 and there are no nan values (which cause change of type) if we were to isin() df1 and df2 - hard to explain but would become obvious if you try to drop all of df2 from df1 using isin() - it will convert the columns to a float.

Comment: Understood. I'm reading the docs and there is the issue WeNYoBen presented (exceeds my knowledge). You can simplify the loop using `df = df.astype(df1.dtypes)`, but you are still changing the datatypes explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from needing to reindex df2 (base dataframe) needing to reindex to match df1 (merging dataframe). It probably should behave as you expect but is an edge case from using the pandas Int64Dtype type instead of python int type.

When preforming the merge, this reindexing is called:

```
> /home/tron/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py(840)_maybe_add_join_keys()
    838                     key_col = rvals
    839                 else:
--> 840                     key_col = Index(lvals).where(~mask, rvals)
    841 
    842                 if result._is_label_reference(name):
```

Which then calls this array dtype.

```
> /home/tron/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py(359)__new__()
    357                 data = ea_cls._from_sequence(data, dtype=dtype, copy=False)
    358             else:
--> 359                 data = np.asarray(data, dtype=object)
    360 
    361             # coerce to the object dtype
```

You can explore this yourself by using the pdb debugger and stepping through the result.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [10, 11, 12]}, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
def test():
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    df = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', indicator=True, suffixes=('_x', ''))
    return df
df = text()
```

---

Some interesting notes:

- If you use `dtype=int` instead of `dtype=pd.Int64Dtype()` the types are actually as expected. It probably should work similar with both but the `int` type has a different logic path in `pandas/core/indexes/base.py(359)__new__()` which interprets int as "# index-like`. That said, you should likely default to using the default` int, float, bool` types from python instead of pandas dtypes unless you have a specific use case.
- `df2.merge(df1, how='inner')` preserves the types because no reindexing is needed.
- `df1.merge(df2, how='outer')` preserves the types because df1 (base dataframe) does not need to reindex to merge df2.